# Amazon S3 in PieCloudDB

Tags: amazon-s3

I have been using Amazon S3 recently，and I would like to synchronize data files from Amazon S3 to PieCloudDB.

Does PieCloudDB database support loading data files directly from external S3 object storage？How can I configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes PieCloudDB database supports this feature. You can follow these steps:

1.Upload the file lineitem.csv to one of the buckets in the object storage.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJHJU.png)

2.Create an s3.conf file in the /home/openpie/ directory on all nodes of PieCloudDB.

```
[default]
secret = "minioadmin"
accessid = "minioadmin"
threadnum = 3
chunksize = 67108864
encryption = false
```

3. Configure the S3 access environment.

```
psql -p 6003 testdb
 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION write_to_s3() RETURNS integer AS
   '$libdir/gps3ext.so', 's3_export' LANGUAGE C STABLE;
 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION read_from_s3() RETURNS integer AS
   '$libdir/gps3ext.so', 's3_import' LANGUAGE C STABLE;
 
CREATE PROTOCOL s3 (writefunc = write_to_s3, readfunc = read_from_s3);
```

4. Create external table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE lineitem_s3_1 ( l_orderkey    integer ,
                             l_partkey     integer ,
                             l_suppkey     integer ,
                             l_linenumber  integer ,
                             l_quantity    decimal(15,2) ,
                             l_extendedprice  decimal(15,2) ,
                             l_discount    decimal(15,2) ,
                             l_tax         decimal(15,2) ,
                             l_returnflag  char(1) ,
                             l_linestatus  char(1) ,
                             l_shipdate    date ,
                             l_commitdate  date ,
                             l_receiptdate date ,
                             l_shipinstruct char(25) ,
                             l_shipmode     char(10) ,
                             l_comment      varchar(44) )
LOCATION('s3://your host name:9000/filetest/lineitem.csv config=/home/openpie/s3.conf')
ON MASTER
FORMAT 'TEXT'(DELIMITER='|');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbNFV.png)

5. Verify data

```
psql -p 6003 testdb
select * from lineitem_s3 limit 10;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmR00.png)